# Angular2: Same url routing cause page refresh

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

This is part of my app NgModule:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', component: testComponent },
            { path: 'test', component: anotherTestComponent }
        ], { useHash: true })
```

That is the only place where i declare my routing.
I'm encountering this problem: starting from root (`/#/`) i go first to *"test"* (`/#/test`) and then move back to root.
Here, if i click enter on address bar (with the root path), my whole app is reloaded. I get the same if i go to *"test"* first and then re-enter the *"test"* path on the address bar.
I didn't test router-link within my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the browser works, when you hit enter on the address bar it triggers a page refresh.

To navigate through a Single Page App you use routes/links inside the app, not hitting enter on the address bar.

Comment: Ok, i thought Angular was able to intercept the call while on the same domain. My bad.

Comment: it's not up to Angular, it's how the Browser works by design. Hitting Enter means REFRESH even if it's the same URL

Comment: But wait a sec: why am i able to press enter the very first time and move to a different route (for example, from root to test) and not from root to root again, or test to test?

Comment: Oh now I see that use the # (hash) , when the hash changes the Browser will not refresh, but if the hash is the same then it will trigger a refresh. Again this is Browser behavior not Angular.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks ;)